# Usage of mathbb versus mathds

Tags: fonts, best-practices

Blissfully unaware of mathds for years I have used  $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}$ and so on. No one has complained but is there a best practice on choosing between mathbb and mathds for these?

There has been discussion here of using mathds for 1 and for A.  Are there other technical issues I should know about in making my choice?

Comment: `\mathds` is presumably defined in some package you haven't stated and gives a double struck alphabet. Like any font choice it is just a style choice.

Comment: Are you interested in just uppercase letters?

Comment: `dsfont` package provides `\mathds{..}` alphabet. If you want to use *that* alphabet, but with the usual command, just do `\let\mathbb\mathds`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is good to be reminded that from a LaTeX team member's viewpoint font choice is just a style choice.  But from a user's viewpoint some choices would be unacceptably odd and others would be not best.

Manuel brings up a technical issue that is decisive for me.  Even using the `amsmath` and `amsfonts` packages you do not have `\mathds`.  Of course I can easily add the `dsfont` package but I can't assume everyone I deal with has it, or wants to add packages for me.

While `mathbb` only handles uppercase letter, `mathds` add numerals.  As far as I can see looking around online, neither handles lowercase letters (which you probably would not want to see doublestruck).

Comment: I see there is a vote to delete.  Is there a problem with the answer?

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph of this answer: in the documentation I have for the `mathds` package (version 1.111, the PDF file says November 29, 2006), besides uppercase letters, `\mathds` supports the figure 1 and lowercase letters h and k (see page 4).

Comment: Sorry for grave-digging but this is a problem I came across recently. As a teacher I want my students to learn to write the double struck letters for the natural numbers, real numbers etc. ... and mathds is the closest I could come to those that I teach my children. It might not matter at a university level, but it might matter in school.